# Is the offset of a flexible array member subject to change?

Tags: c

The standard—§6.7.2.1.18—says that

> However, when a . (or ->) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, **even if this would differ from that of the replacement array**.

The problem is that i don't understand what the standard means by the last statement. Given that we usually set aside enough memory—using malloc()—for a flexible array member *along with* that of other members, how can it be possible to have non-successive offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that if we have:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    int a[];
};

struct B
{ 
    int x;
    int b[20];
};

// ...
A *pa = malloc(sizeof(struct A) + sizeof(int[20]));
B *pb = malloc(sizeof(struct B));
```

then `ptr->a` behaves exactly like `ptr->b` except that `offsetof(struct B, b)` and `offsetof(struct A, a)`, which are both compile-time constants, may be different.

There are some examples in the following paragraphs.

NB. They also behave differently under the action of `sizeof` so this paragraph seems to be a bit defective.

Comment: Is it because of a structure padding?

Comment: @user227248 sorry, what?

Comment: I mean, the data should be at a memory offset which is some multiple of a word.

Comment: `a` and `b` must be correctly aligned for `int` of course. However there could be different amounts of padding between `x` and `a` than there is between `x` and `b`.